# How to add html into DOM with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if it's jquery, we can do like `$('table-row').clone().preprenTo($('table'));`

I know it's just push a new value into an object in adding new data but I want to first insert the empty row and field first, how to add that html with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John added a link to a famous question/answer regarding AngularJS. I would advice you to read that.

That said, to answer your question - in angular you do not tell it how to manipulate the dom. You tell it what data you have and how you want it presented.

I can only guess to what you are trying to do, but if you have a template (your 'table-row') and a 'destination' ('table') you would describe it in AngularJS like this:

```
<table ng-controller="PersonsController">
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <td>{{person.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.Address}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That is great, but how do you add a row? Well you don't "add a row" - you add a person and AngularJS will do the adding of rows for you. You already explained how you want a person displayed.

To add a person you would have to add a person to a list/array of persons and that list would be in the scope of your view/application.

```
persons.push({Name: 'Bill', Address: 'Somewhere'});
```

You will need to attach the persons to your scope, which you will do in a controller. A controller would have to be associated with the code above with the `ng-controller` directive.

```
app.controller('PersonsController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.persons = [];
});
```

In the above code i assume you have a variable `app` pointing to your angular application. There is a small learning curve you will have to overcome, going from jquery to angular. Mostly, the way i see it, is moving your mindset from a imperative coding style to a declarative coding style.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need a paradigm shift. Read ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1).

Then, if you still think that your problem is best solved by adding a row to the DOM, consider using an AngularJS [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: is there any simpler way? jquery did that with one line of code, how many lines I need for angularjs?

Comment: If all you want to do is manipulate the DOM then you shouldn't use AngularJS. jQuery is fine for that purpose. If you want to build single-page applications and reusable client-side web components, then AngularJS is awesome. It's really a question of what kind of application you want to build.

Comment: I wrote in angular before but I forgot how to do it. Can u take a look?http://jsfiddle.net/u9gce3f2/ How to add an empty field?

Comment: Sure, if you can post to Plunker or something.

Comment: I'm surprised you chose Angular 1.0.3. If that's a hard requirement then I still recommend using ngRepeat, but you may encounter other issues. If you can use a later version of AngularJS then this will do it. http://jsfiddle.net/fxm3eg2j/